# Set Form Errors NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs

How can I set the form errors in NGXS. I saw that there is UpdateFormErrors action in the plugin but there is no documentation on how to use it.

I tried with the following:

```
  const errors = {
      errors: response.error,
      path: "product.productForm.name"
    }

    dispatch(new UpdateFormErrors(errors));
```

But to no lack. The errors are not binded in the form.

My HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" ngxsForm="product.productForm" class="m-t">
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"><input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product name"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"><input formControlName="price" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea formControlName="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                <button (click)="onSubmit()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" data-style="expand-right">Submit</button>
                <button (click)="sample()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" data-style="expand-right">Sample</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

How can I set the form errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from the [source code](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/cc37637b92f14dbb5025124b114598f69f610be1/packages/form-plugin/src/directive.ts) for form plugin, `UpdateFormErrors` is supposed to be used for form-level errors.

So at the very least you should use `path: "product.productForm"` instead of `path: "product.productForm.name"`.

If you want `errors` container in the form state to be filled using form controls' data, [this issue](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/654) seems to be relevant to your problem.

Comment: I try and will let you know. But as far as I understand the issue you linked, there is no way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, I guess it's not possible with inbuilt functionaltity atm.

Answer (score 1):

**Error Handling using NGXS and Form**

in NGXS form there is 4 options in form

1. model / controlers
2. error
3. dirty
4. status

Make a class with name of productStatModel and keep this in use like this

```
productForm : {
 model:  undefined;
    dirty : false;
    status : '';
    errors: : null;
 }
```

now in store class use it selector and reducer

```
@Selector()
static productErrors(state: productStateModel) { return 
state.productForm.errors; }
```

in component
use selector with observable

```
@Action(ProductAction.update)
login(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    return this.updateService.update(productForm.model).pipe(
        tap((resp) => {
            ctx.patchState({
                // on success add what you want
            });

        }),
        catchError((err) => {
            // in case of Backend required error
            ctx.setState({
                ...state,
                productForm: {
                    ...state.producForm,
                    errors: err,
                }
            });
            throw err;
        })
    );
}
```

At component

```
@Select(ProductState.productErrors) errors$: Observable<any>;
```

now use this error Observable in HTML binding

```
<div>{{(error$ | async).name}}</div>
```

Comment: This is good for server side errors what about client side errors